# Is there a way to rewind or step back when using JsonReader?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to read the first property name from a JSON object input stream, and then based on its value, maybe "rewind" and read the whole object.

I can read the first property name easily like

```
JsonReader reader = ...;
while (reader.Read()) {
  if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName) {
    // this is the first property
    break;
  }
}
```

But I can't see any method to step back or rewind the reader.

While I understand that lower level seeking might not be supported by the underlying stream, I would expect that JSON tokens which we've already read could be rewinded and re-parsed somehow.

If this is not possible, alternatively is there any way to read only the property names of an object without parsing the contents of each property? I'd like to avoid reading the whole stuff twice only for examining one property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  [`JsonReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm) is a forward-only reader.  There is no way to "rewind" or seek back to an earlier stage without completely reparsing from the beginning.  If you want to be able to see earlier information then you'll need to store it into variables as you read it.

`JsonReader` does provide a [`Skip`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Skip.htm) method which can be used to skip over children of a particular token.  So if you read the name of a property which you're not interested in, and the next token is the start of an object or array, you can use `Skip` to move directly to the end token for that object or array.

Below is a simple example which uses this technique to read only the root property names of a JSON object but skip over all the values.

```
string json = @"
{
  ""resultCode"": 200,
  ""message"": ""OK"",
  ""searchTerms"": [
    {
      ""attribute"": ""keywords"",
      ""operator"": ""contains"",
      ""values"": [ ""ipsum"" ]
    }
  ],
  ""count"": 2,
  ""items"": [
    {
      ""id"": 1,
      ""name"": ""foo"",
      ""sizes"": [ ""small"", ""meduim"", ""large"" ],
      ""description"": ""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet""
    },
    {
      ""id"": 2,
      ""name"": ""bar"",
      ""sizes"": [ ""tiny"", ""huge"" ],
      ""description"": ""Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum""
    }
  ]
}";

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(json))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
        {
            string propName = (string)reader.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(propName);

            // advance to property value
            reader.Read();

            // if the value is an object or array, skip over its children
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject ||
                reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
                reader.Skip();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
resultCode
message
searchTerms
count
items
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qfejWk

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question for System.Text.Json which led me here, and I found a solution, I figured I should share the answer here.

As suggested by Levi Broderick [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30083#issuecomment-747092027), the new `Utf8JsonReader` is a struct, which means it can be copied at will.

```cs
Utf8JsonReader reader2 = reader;

reader2.Read();// ... Do stuff with the copy of the reader

// Here the initial reader didn't change and is still where you left it.
```

That way, you could parse the data twice as I did [here](https://github.com/jeremyVignelles/ooak/blob/3cb644e002f8f58fd91b1144d99c9b58194594f2/Ooak/SystemTextJson/OoakSystemTextJsonConverter.cs#L86) or [there](https://github.com/jeremyVignelles/SystemTextJsonPolymorphicDeserialization/blob/master/PolymorphicConverter.cs)

With Newtonsoft.Json, I finally used `JToken.ReadFrom(reader)`, and then did my stuff from there. See [this code](https://github.com/jeremyVignelles/ooak/blob/3cb644e002f8f58fd91b1144d99c9b58194594f2/Ooak/NewtonsoftJson/OoakNewtonsoftJsonConverter.cs#L62)

```cs
JToken token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
var left = token.ToObject<TLeft>(serializer);
var right = token.ToObject<TRight>(serializer);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution, it has really useful information.

Comment: This is apparently what System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer does if an exception is thrown during deserialization.